# Typeahead and bloodhound post request not working in Laravel 5

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5, typeahead, bloodhound

This is my HTML Code:

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="chiefComplaintInput" name="chiefComplaintInp" class="typeahead-chiefcomplaint form-control input-circle-right" placeholder="Chief Complaints">
```

This is my Jquery bloodhound and typeahead code:

```
var chiefComplaints = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(resp) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(resp.value);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        wildcard: '%QUERY',
        url: "/opd/searchChiefComplaints/",
            transform: function(response) {
                return $.map(response, function(restaurant) {
                    return { value: restaurant.name };
                });
            }
        }
});

$('input#chiefComplaintInput').typeahead({
    hint: false,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 2,
    limit: 10
},
{
    name: 'chiefComplaints',
    display: 'value',
    source: chiefComplaints,
    templates: {
            header: '<h4 class="dropdown">Restaurants</h4>'
    }   
});
```

This is the routes that i ahve defined:

```
Route::get('opd/searchChiefComplaints/{queryParam}', 'OpdController@searchChiefComplaints');
```

This is the controller code:

```
public function searchChiefComplaints(Request $request)
  {
    // return Response::json($request->get('queryParam'));
    return $request->get('queryParam');
  }
```

What i am trying to achieve is that i want to send post request to the controller and receive the JSON in response. Bu i am having problem attaining it i dont know where my code is going wrong :(

Comment: use inspect in google chrome 'network' tab to analyze your request to backend. you can see some info here in respone section. Also you can analyze your log file in laravel folder to see what's wrong.

Comment: Nopes tried that all no reponse

Answer (score 0):

JSON posted data cannot be read by `$request->get()`. You should use `$request->input()`.

See this (declined) PR: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/13566#issue-154985037